# How to change hover size of link elements to take full box width/height of area which text contained

Tags: css, hover, navbar

I have a navbar that is set to display an `inline-block`. When, I added the `hover` pseudo class to change the color on hover. I want the color of the hover state to take full width/height of area. Right now its just taking enough space to cover the text.

[link to my code on codepen](http://codepen.io/sandyngomez/pen/rVRZqE?editors=110)

Comment: http://codepen.io/sandyngomez/pen/rVRZqE?editors=110

Comment: The requirement to have code accompanying all links to codepen is there for a reason... Please add your code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a CSS reset to disable all the default browser stylings, If you check the demo you put in the first post, by default `<ul></ul>` have a `margin-top: browser-value;` and a `margin-bottom: browser-value;`, by adding a `margin: 0;` to your `<ul></ul>` the anchor tags (`<a></a>`) inside will resize probably, This is a [forked version of the codepen demo](http://codepen.io/Youssefsh/pen/JdzgjV) you had earlier, And i just applied a CSS reset through the CSS panel in codepen, For this specific part I used a normal reset, but if you want to read more about resets and understand how they work the following [link](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/) will give you a lot of insight.